# Binding was not executed in CommandBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, commandbinding

i have this xaml code:

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="WpfApplication1:MainCommands.Search" Executed="Search"/>
</Window.CommandBindings><Grid>
<StackPanel>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SearchContext}" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}">
        <TextBox.InputBindings>
            <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{x:Static WpfApplication1:MainCommands.Search}" />
        </TextBox.InputBindings>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

The Search-Method looks like:

```
private void Search(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SearchContext = new ObservableCollection<string>(list.Where(element => element.Name == LastName).Select(el => el.Name).ToList());
}
```

MainCommands:

```
public static class MainCommands
{
    public static RoutedCommand Search = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

But if i press enter while focus is in textbox, the binding is´nt computet and LastName is Null. What is the reason? How can I avoid this? Or is it possible to explicit call the binding operation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property to `PropertyChanged`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

This will cause the source property (`LastName`) to be set immediately: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As I can see your `Window` is a view-model for it. I recommend you to use MVVM and have separate class for view-model where you can place desired `ICommand` and use `CommandParameter` on `KeyBinding`:

```
<TextBox x:Name="searchBox"
         Text="{Binding LastName}">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                    Command="{Binding Path=SearchCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=searchBox}" />
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```